# Mechanize you different ip

Tags: python, proxy, ip, mechanize

I'm playing around with mechanize on a website that appears differently based on your ip.

Is there a way to change you ip in mechanize?

I've tried:

```
br.set_proxies({"http": '127.0.0.1:80'})
```

but that timesout.  Is there something else I'm supposed to do to make this work?

Comment: You'd need to get your machine's (or router's) TCP stack to request a new IP (assuming you're on DHCP). This is very non-trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, I do not believe this is possible.  IP address is set on outgoing packets by your network stack, outside of mechanize's control.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tor with menchanize it will allowed you tu use different IP and anonymous.

```
import socks
import socket


def create_connection(address, timeout=None, source_address=None):
    sock = socks.socksocket()
    sock.connect(address)
    return sock
```

And This code before create the browser of mechanize

```
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)

socket.socket = socks.socksocket
socket.create_connection = create_connection
```